# How can I convert "SELECT col, COUNT(*)" to a Linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this query

```
SELECT Reaction, COUNT(*) as 'Votes' FROM Member_Reaction mr
    WHERE mr.[Entitiy ID] = '259F16A0-9635-4F58-B645-0AEBAAC09D46'
    GROUP BY Reaction
```

How can I convert this to Linq?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

```
var query = from item in db.MemberReactions
            where item.ID == id
            group item by item.Reaction into g
            select new { Reaction = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

(Where `id` is the ID you're looking for - as a GUID, or a string, or whatever the right type is.)

Comment: `Reaction into g` that was what I missed. Thanks.